# Javascript console in HTML

Tags: javascript

So basically, like the Developer console - where you can see the outputs to the console via console.log etc....

I want to implement something like this so I can see this on the actual html page instead of having to open the Developer console.

Is there a way of doing this?
Thanks!

Comment: Sure is, but it's a lot of work. There's a reason those tools are *native*. Good luck!

Comment: this is a tad too broad ;) SO is more about answering specific questions.. Q&A style!

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Actually, for a REPL, all you need is `eval()`.  Being native doesn't help.

Comment: See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/16616794/2632619   http://stackoverflow.com/a/6604660/2632619

Answer (score 0):

You could use a implementation of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16616794/1175881) like this: (note - This is the code from that answer. Only the part `former(msg)` gave me an error, so I left that part out)

```
console.log = function(msg){
    $("#mylog").append("<div>" + msg + "</div>");
}

window.onerror = function(message, url, linenumber) {
    console.log("JavaScript error: " + message + " on line " + 
                linenumber + " for " + url);
}
console.log("test");
console.log("test");
va
```

And the HTML

```
<div id="mylog"></div>
```

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pUaYn/44/)

Comment: I use `console.dir` all the time. How would you implement this? Because right now it just throws, and that doesn't help. In fact that reminds me, can your console show error messages?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I'm not quiet sure. (this is mostly out of my league). But I've updated my answer with a another SO answer, maybe that answer will answer your question?

Comment: Well I hate to be a downer, but if you're answering a question by copying in stuff from another answer, then that's kinda plagiarism and also a sign that you should be voting to close as a duplicate. Now, you don't have your close-vote permission yet, but you will, and whenever you're tempted to copy another answer into yours, consider close-voting as duplicate instead.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I totally agree with you. But I was in a good mood, so that's why I "helped".